# rn-pdf-reader not working with react native expo SDK 49 in android

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

**PDF reader not working after updating expo SDK 48 to expo SDK 49 in android device.**

Reproducible snack link : https://snack.expo.dev/@kirtikk/pdfreader-expo-49

Nodejs version: 18.12.0,
React version: 18.2.0,
React Native version: 0.72.6,
rn-pdf-reader-js version: 4.1.1,
Platform(s) (iOS, Android, or both?): both
Expo version: 49.0.0.

**Error : Cannot convert null value to object**